# PHP preg_match get content between

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
<!--:en-->Apvalus šviestuvas<!--:-->
<!--:ru-->Круглый Светильник<!--:-->
<!--:lt-->Round lighting<!--:-->
```

I need get the content between  `<!--:lt-->` and `<!--:-->`

I have tried:

```
$string  = "<!--:en-->Apvalus šviestuvas<!--:--><!--:ru-->Круглый Светильник<!--:--><!--:lt-->Round lighting<!--:-->";
preg_match('<!--:lt-->+[a-zA-Z0-9]+<!--:-->$', $string, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

Something is wrong with the syntax and logic.  How can I make this work?

Comment: First of all you have to escape meta characters (:!-)

Comment: @hindmost `:` and `!` are not metacharacters, `-` is not a metacharacter unless it's inside `[]`. At least not in POSIX.

Comment: I did mean "reserved" characters. In general case `:` and `!` should be escaped in order to avoid improper interpretation.

Comment: @hindmost: Why? Where have you seen that?

Comment: @hindmost maybe you're referring to `?:` - the non-matching group. The colon does not appear on it's own. I'm not sure what you think `!` is used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("/<!--:lt-->([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?)<!--:-->/", $string, $match);
```

- added delimiters
- added a match group
- added `?` to make it ungreedy
- added `[space]` (there is a space in `Round lighting`)

Your result should be in `$match[1]`.

---

A cooler and more generic variation is:

```
preg_match_all("/<!--:([a-z]+)-->([^<]+)<!--:-->/", $string, $match);
```

Which will match all of them. Gives:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(37) "Apvalus šviestuvas" [1]=> string(53) "Круглый Светильник" [2]=> string(32) "Round lighting" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "en" [1]=> string(2) "ru" [2]=> string(2) "lt" } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "Apvalus šviestuvas" [1]=> string(35) "Круглый Светильник" [2]=> string(14) "Round lighting" } }
```

Comment: the lazy quantifier is not needed since the next character is not inside the character class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Pattern   `(?<=<!--:lt-->)(.*)(?=<!--:-->)`

```
<?php
$string  = "<!--:en-->Apvalus šviestuvas<!--:--><!--:ru-->Круглый Светильник<!--:--><!--:lt-->Round lighting<!--:-->";
preg_match('~(?<=<!--:lt-->)(.*)(?=<!--:-->)~', $string, $match);

var_dump($match);
```